# symfony2 embedded collection edit form issue

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, editing

I have a problem with edititng embedded collection form. I have two object with many-to-one relation. When I create an object "Good" with related "photos" all successfully. When I update the Good object by adding some new photos all works fine too. But, if I try to delete a one photo in some Good object after update photo is not deleted.

Good.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="good", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
**/
private $photos;

/**
 * Add photos
 *
 * @param \VDKP\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Photo $photos
 * @return Good
 */
public function addPhoto(\VDKP\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Photo $photos)
{
    $photos->setGood($this);

    $this->photos->add($photos);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove photos
 *
 * @param \VDKP\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Photo $photos
 */
public function removePhoto(\VDKP\Site\BackendBundle\Entity\Photo $photos)
{
    $this->photos->removeElement($photos);
}

/**
 * Get photos
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPhotos()
{
    return $this->photos;
}
```

Photo.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Good", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="good_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $good;
```

GoodController, updateACtion:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('VDKPSiteBackendBundle:Good')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Good entity.');
    }

    $originalPhotos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($entity->getPhotos() as $photo) {
        $originalPhotos->add($photo);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {


        foreach ($originalPhotos as $photo) {
            if (false === $entity->getPhotos()->contains($photo)) {
                $photo->setGood(null);

                $em->persist($photo);                
            }
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('good_edit', array('id' => $id)));

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );

}
```

I did everything as written in the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Sorry for my english. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't see the snippet of code where you use `removePhoto()` method

Comment: It's `$photo->setGood(null);` that doesn't look good to me. Why didn't you use `$good->getPhotos()->removeElement($photo);` ?

Comment: Because I have many to one relation between photo and good entities

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed this part of docs:

```
foreach ($originalTags as $tag) {
    if (false === $task->getTags()->contains($tag)) {
        // remove the Task from the Tag
        $tag->getTasks()->removeElement($task);

        // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
        // $tag->setTask(null);

        $em->persist($tag);

        // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
        // $em->remove($tag);
    }
}
```

So, I think you have to do something similar with your data types: Good and Photo.

Comment: It`s code in my updateAction: `foreach ($originalPhotos as $photo) {
  if (false === $entity->getPhotos()->contains($photo)) {
  $photo->setGood(null);

                $em->persist($photo);                
            }
        }`

Comment: No, it's not. You only do setGood() but don't remove anything. Check it out once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think, documentation is inaccurate, because:

In this part of code:

```
$originalTags = new ArrayCollection();

// Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
   $originalTags->add($tag);
}
```

we collect Tags, which have relations with current Task in database.

In this part of code:

```
foreach ($originalTags as $tag) {
    if (false === $task->getTags()->contains($tag)) {
        // remove the Task from the Tag
        $tag->getTasks()->removeElement($task);

        // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
        // $tag->setTask(null);

        $em->persist($tag);

        // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
        // $em->remove($tag);
    }
}
```

we must compare $request data and $originalTags array data. But, we compare $originalTags with $task->getTags(), which is essentially the same.

Comment: If you change some fields' values in form, submit it, and call `$myEntity->getMyField()` it returns the changed value however you didn't flush it yet (but you can see original (unchanged) value in your entity's table if you look at the db table at this moment), this is somekind of `data_class` job I think..